# Bookmark icon changes need them changed back

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, favicon

Why would we want to visit every bookmark we have just because Chrome decided to change the icons. I have 1000's, there has to be a way to change them back to normal without loading of every one in turn.

Comment: Yes annoying, some extensions or malware can cause this, it is not default behavior. What I do once I have all my icons is to backup the Favicons file in "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default" for Windows and "~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default" for Mac

Comment: Then if they get borked again you can restore the favicons file back in that location.

Comment: Sometimes signing out of chrome then sign back in fixes it also>>>>>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s86hIpXh4Rc

Comment: Be sure chrome is up to date also, there were bugs in older versions that did this.